# How to get control of tab after refreshing a webpage using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, ui-automation

1. I am writing automation test scenario using selenium webdriver in java and cucumber.
2. Scenario:

   2.1 I have two tabs(Parent tab and child tab). I will switch to child tab.

   2.2 After switching to child tab and I will refresh a page. After that, I need to click an button in that page.
3. The problem, Which I am facing is I am unable to click that button element present in that page.

Note:- If I don't refresh a page means, I am able to click that button element in that page.

4. Even, I tried to get the current url, I am able to get the correct child tab url.
5. As per my observation, controlling is missing after giving the refresh page via automation.
6. Can anyone suggest the solution to handle control, after refreshing an web

Sample Code:

```
   @Given("^I choose Segments menu$")
public void I_choose_Segments_menu() throws Exception {
    getSegmentsCentralDSL().clickDmpSegmentsButton();
    segmentCentralPage.getDmpSegmentGrid();
    segmentCentralPage.refreshPage();
    Thread.sleep(20000);

    ArrayList tabs = new ArrayList(segmentCentralPage.getDriver()
            .getWindowHandles());
    System.out.println(tabs.size());

    segmentCentralPage.getDriver().switchTo()
            .window(tabs.get(1).toString());
    String currentUrl = segmentCentralPage.getDriver().getCurrentUrl();
    System.out.println("currentUrl=" + windowTitle);

}
```

Comment: Can you share your html before and after the refresh?

Comment: Before you are clicking the button you need to find the button again using driver.findElement, as the previous reference to the button is gone when the page is refreshed. Are you searching for this again?

Comment: try switching to window again after refresh, "segmentCentralPage.getDriver().switchTo()
            .window(tabs.get(1).toString());", and find the elem, then try to click